# how can i know if `org.apache.http.client` uses Java NIO and if that's profitable to me to change to NIO?

Tags: java, apache, nio

I have this code:

```
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import com.google.inject.Inject;


public class GenericHttpClient implements IGenericHttpClient {

    private CloseableHttpClient client;

    @Inject
    @Singleton
    public GenericHttpClient() {
//        client = HttpClientBuilder.createForBl()
//                .setConnectionTimeToLive(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
//                .build();


        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(20 * 1000)
                .build();
        client = HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();


    }

    @Override
    public String sendHttpGetRequest(String url) {
//        Constants.CONFIG_QUERY_URL
        String answer = null;
        try {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                answer = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

how can I know if `org.apache.http.client` uses Java NIO or NIO.2 underneath its API? Is there another library which i can use that implements NIO underneath?

In addition, all I do with networking is `GET` and return an object with the response as one of the object members.

So my thread will be blocked for `Future.get()` very after the NIO. I'm not sure I'm saving any resources then.

```
//Send the message

Future<Integer> successfullyWritten=  asynchronousSocketChannel.write(helloBuffer);

//Do some stuff here. The point here is that asynchronousSocketChannel.write() 
//returns almost immediately, not waiting to actually finish writing 
//the hello to the channel before returning control to the currently executing thread

doSomethingElse();

//now you can come back and check if it was all written (or not)

System.out.println("Bytes written "+successfullyWritten.get());
```

Comment: If you care about what it uses underneath, you should perhaps write the code yourself? The point of using a library is to abstract what it does underneath.

Comment: Side-note: from [the docs](https://hc.apache.org/): *HttpCore supports two I/O models: blocking I/O model based on the classic Java I/O and non-blocking, event driven I/O model based on Java NIO.*

Comment: I'm considering performance issue. Is there another library which i can use that implements NIO underneath?

Comment: Performance of HTTP clients is determined by the network, not by the I/O API. There is no point to this enquiry.

Comment: but why, won't non-blocking threads be faster than blocking thread? or you mean I can control this on top of apache HTTP client?